# How to delay api call, till access token is retrieved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, oauth-2.0, restangular

I am using AngularJs for my project. Backend is a REST server using OAuth2 for authentication. I need to fetch access token before I can make any API call. I am using Restangular for API calls.

How do I delay normal API calls till I have retrieved access token from server?

Answer (score 2):

Look at libraries like this one
https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

They provide a mechanism to retry the failed requests once you have authentication token. Basically this library implements a http interceptor for the same.

Comment: your answer is for the failed request. What if the api can be called with/without access token, but the response is different. In my case this api was called by logged-in user without access token first and succeeded, but then the response is like non-loggedin user bcs there is no access token.